# Assume a system has infinite amount of main memory, then is virtual memory still needed?

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual-memory

We have an arbitrarily large amount of main memory. Why do we still need virtual memory then, since there is no need to create the appearance of 'more memory than is available physically', since we just have infinite memory. Do we still need virtual memory then? Why or why not?

Comment: Process protection, and virtualizing devices/files to make them look like memory.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks for answering. I am a newbie to this, so could you please explain a bit more?